# NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/asm4/ClassReader on IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 Build #IU-135.1229

Tags: intellij-idea, scala-2.10

I have following warning:

```
Warning:scalac: Class dependency information may be incomplete! Error parsing generated class /Users/admin/Server_Projects/DatingServer/target/scala-2.10/classes/reactive/Globals.class
Error: org/jetbrains/asm4/ClassReader
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/asm4/ClassReader
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeClientIdea.generated(IdeClientIdea.scala:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:25)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.handle(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.using(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.using(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.using(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.using(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.using(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.using(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.send(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.compile(RemoteServer.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:39)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:536)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:38)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:38)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:37)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate.compile(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:37)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.IdeaIncrementalBuilder$.build(IdeaIncrementalBuilder.scala:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder.build(ScalaBuilder.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1106)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:814)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:862)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:777)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:600)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:184)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.asm4.ClassReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 48 more
Warning:scalac: Class dependency information may be incomplete! Error parsing generated class /Users/admin/Server_Projects/DatingServer/target/scala-2.10/classes/reactive/Globals$.class
Error: org/jetbrains/asm4/ClassReader
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/asm4/ClassReader
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeClientIdea.generated(IdeClientIdea.scala:52)
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem after an update of IntelliJ (13.1.4).

The problem was solved by updating the Scala plugin to version 0.38.441.

Comment: yeah, you are absolutely right! Thanks @Sébastien Mosser to solving my question!